# C# is to .NET as Java is to?

Tags: java, c#, .net

I am learning `C#,` and I just want to get a conceptual answer question. I've read a little about how to program in C# and every tutorial makes tons of references to `.NET`, and I still have an unclear understanding of the relation. So far I've gathered that .NET is a software framework that has built-in structures and libraries, etc. that people programming in C# can implement. Correct me on this if needed, please :)

I learned `Java` a couple years ago and I was wondering if there's a similar 'framework' Java uses/is part of. 
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft's .NET is **a platform**. The platform consists of three types of building blocks:

1. Common Language Runtime (**CLR**). It locates, loads and manages .NET objects and takes care of a number of low-level details (memory management, threads, security checks etc).
2. Common Type System (**CTS**). It fully describes all possible data types and programming constructs supported by the runtime, specifies how these entities can interact with each other etc
3. Common Language Specification (**CLS**). IT specifies a subset of common types and programming constructs that all .NET languages can agree on.

[image]
Source: [Abdelrahman Hosny](http://abdelrahmanhosny.com/2012/07/24/introduction-to-microsoft-net-framework-solution/)

You can find [more information here](http://www.luisleo.net/the-atom-of-the-net-framework/).

### Java and .NET platforms

Java has its own virtual machine, the Java Virtual Machine (**JVM**) which is similar to .NET CLR.

Java's execution engine (the JVM) and a Java compiler with a set of libraries constitute the [Java Platform.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_platform) So, to answer your question Java and .Net have many differences and many more similarities but one could say that "*C# is to .NET as Java is to.. Java Platform*".

Some people, for simplicity may say "Java" but what they really want to say is "The Java Platform".

Answer (score 8):

.Net is a family of languages (VB.Net, F#, C#, etc) that all compile down to the same IL (intermediary language) which is executed by the CLR (common language run time).

IL is equivalent to Java byte code and the CLR is the equivalent to the Java VM.

If there was another language that compiled down to Java bytecode and ran on the Java VM I guess you could call this the 'Java Family'.  The 'Java Family' would be equivalent to .Net.

Comment: There are plenty such languages, actually.

Comment: @Joey, I'm primarily a C# developer so I'm not that familiar with the Java world.  What are some of the languages?

Comment: @Јοеу - I'm curious too coming from another .net guy. I always assumed the JVM was only for java.

Comment: @ppittle Anyone can write a language that uses the JVM as long as it emits Java bytecode. Scala and Clojure are examples of languages implemented on top of the JVM that are not Java

Comment: To directly answer the question posed by the title.  You can relate the .NET Framework version to the Java (JRE) version.  Java runs on the base Java libraries, and C# runs on the .NET Framework libraries.

Comment: Scala, Groovy, Clojure are the more prominent ones, then there are lots of established languages running on the JVM, e.g. Jython or JRuby, etc. A list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages). @Smith.h.Neil: The JVM originally was very closely aligned in both features and behaviour to what Java, the language needed. However, more recently they looked at .NET and determined that having a runtime (and it's a pretty damn good runtime) having different languages running on top of it, is a very nice thing to have.

Comment: Two members of the Java family I'm aware of are Scala and Groovy. There are tons of language implementations specifically targeting the JVM: JRuby (Ruby), Clojure (Lisp), Rhino (Javascript)...

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. .Net is a framework, not a "family of languages".

Comment: @Joe, The .Net Framework Libraries (or Base Class Libraries or BCL) don't 'execute' .Net code.  They contain common functions, but it's the CLR (common language runtime) that actually translates jit-ed IL into machine code and hosts the process that executes it.

Comment: @ppittle - This is correct, I am comparing the .NET Framwork libraries to the core java libraries which also contain common functions.  CLR=JVM these actually execute the code.

Comment: @Joey - are the languages you listed interoperable?  Can you can JRuby code from Jython or from Java?

Comment: @Joey, Thanks for the explanation. I really need to get comfortable outside of the .net world.

Comment: @ppittle: Usually they all can call Java code at least. Whether it works in the other direction depends a bit on how things are organised at the bytecode level. E.g. in the JVM there cannot be methods without a corresponding class, although you can define those in Python or Ruby. I'm not terribly familiar on how those languages do that. I'm usually a .NET guy as well.